# Protect URL from different user browser

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

Application built in: React and .NET web api

Process:

I have created GET Api in backend for download image from azure blob. In the request, User[Frontend] pass (login)auth token and Image URL to backend as queary string. After validation of auth token backend return binary data to app.

Sample URL: `https://***:4412/file/downlaodFile?filePath=~/Uploads/Images/576659969_911903629_flower-color-400x391.jpg&authToken=da72e5bc0d35d692a4c85e8442366713fc9494c8cf56aa1f326560d06a24db5c16e562b82ad5f86e74d8e417c9695007922c9678c91ea234fa7675164eeb041b`

Problem: After login if user copy that URL and send it to other people so they can also download Image because Auth token is valid for 15 mins.

How can I protect that URL..?

Thnaks!!

Answer (score 0):

You want to put the auth token in the `headers` of the request; never ever put the auth token in the url for security concerns.

More information about the Authorization header can be found here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization

Comment: It is also possible to store your auth token in a session/cookie variable. In that case you don't need the Authorization header.